# Text extraction under specific tag in python XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'd like to select "p" tag under "statement" tag and get all text of under those p tag.

Headache is  tag and it separates necessary text.
(ex  "THIS IS A HIGHLIGHTED statement." -> "THIS IS A ")
Actual data is not only  tag. More variety and complicated of modifier tag.

Desired output:

```
THIS IS A HIGHLIGHTED statement.Test2
THIS IS STATEMENT 2.
```

I've tried 3ways, but they don't work.

```
1,
for element in root.iter('..//statement//p/'):
    print(element.text)
-> nothing found.

2,
for element in root.iter('..//p/..[@attrib="flg"]'):
    print(element.text)
-> nothing found.

3,
print(''.join(root.itertext('p')))
-> error
```

Here is example code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

test_xml='''
<concept>
<title>TITLE</title>
<conbody>
<statement>
<tgroup>
<thead>
<row>
<entry>
<p/>
</entry>
</row>
</thead>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry><ul><li><p flg="1">THIS IS A <xref>HIGHLIGHTED</xref> statement.</p><p flg="1">Test2</p></li></ul></entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry><ul><li><p flg="1">THIS IS STATEMENT 2.</p></li></ul></entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</tgroup>
</statement>
<p>This is an example text1.</p>
</conbody>
<p>This is an example text2.</p>
</concept>'''

root = ET.fromstring(test_xml)

# for element in root.iter('..//statement//p/'):
#     print(element.text)

# for element in root.iter('..//p/..[@attrib="flg"]'):
#     print(element.text)

print(''.join(root.itertext('p')))
```

Comment: The `itertext()` method is applied on an element; it does not take an element name as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) module for this.

You can parse entire XML in a dict and then further extract the data as you want.

```
dict_ = xmltodict.parse(test_xml)
s = dict_['concept']['conbody']['statement']['tgroup']['tbody']['row']
print(s)
```

will give you

```
[{'entry': {'ul': {'li': {'p': [{'@flg': '1', 'xref': 'HIGHLIGHTED', '#text': 'THIS IS A  statement.'}, {'@flg': '1', '#text': 'Test2'}]}}}}, {'entry': {'ul': {'li': {'p': {'@flg': '1', '#text': 'THIS IS STATEMENT 2.'}}}}}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise.
How can I merge the modifier and text? 'xref' and 'text' is still separated in the output.

Comment: @strogm that is because your xml is defined that way. You have to extract from it in whatever way you may see fir.

Comment: Then I understand that a way to remove unnecessary tags is needed...

Comment: @strogm consider asking another question for that, please accept this answer since answer for this question is resolved